# Light4J Total Requests Processed

Tags: java, logging, python-requests, light-4j

I'm using Light-4J as microserver, sitting between my clients and a 3rd party API. Everything is setup and working, the clients are able to POST requests and responses are sent in reply.

However I want to know how many requests have been processed since the server started. Since I use Log4j to each successful API call I thought I might be able to read the number of lines in the log file. This works but is not accurate since I discovered that other processes are also writing to the file so the total is skewed.

Is there another way to get the data I require without me having to ensure that my requests have exclusive access to a log file?

Answer (score 1):

light-4j supports metrics that can be pushed to influxdb or pulled by prometheus. You can enable it in your microservice service.yml or handler.yml (if you are using release 1.5.18 or later)

https://www.networknt.com/concern/metrics/
https://www.networknt.com/concern/prometheus/

If you generate the project from light-codegen, then the Influxdb metrics is wired in but disabled. You just need to install an InfluxDB instance and enabled it in your microservice.

Also, if you only need to proxy to your backend service, light-proxy might be the way to go unless you have some business logic in your microservice.